# C# save to json file using DataContractJsonSerializer

Tags: c#, .net, json, serialization, datacontractjsonserializer

I want to save the data to the JSON file.

Using many examples on the internet, I tried to do it, but it still does not work.

```cs
[DataContract]
[KnownType(typeof(PressureSensor))]
[KnownType(typeof(TemperatureAndHumiditySensor))]
[KnownType(typeof(HumidityAndPressureSensor))]
class WeatherStation
{
    [DataMember]
    private List<Sensor> sensors = new List<Sensor>();

    [DataMember]
    public double period;

    private void SerialzieToJson()
    {
        DataContractJsonSerializer data = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(WeatherStation));
        MemoryStream memory = new MemoryStream();
        data.WriteObject(memory, this);
        memory.Position = 0;

        using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(@"C:\Users\Adżi\Desktop\files\file.json", FileMode.Open))
        {
            memory.CopyTo(stream);
            stream.Flush();
        }

        memory.Position = 0;
        StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(memory);
        Console.WriteLine("JSON: " + streamReader.ReadToEnd());
        streamReader.Close();
        memory.Close(); 
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Why is nothing saved in the file?

Comment: Could you explain what doesn't work ? Does your code throws an exception, does it generates an empty file ?

Comment: The file to which I want to save the data exists.
The code does not throw an exception. 
It looks like it works well, but the file is empty.

Comment: Try adding try..catch.. within SerialzieToJson method.
And try to change the directory to C:\Temp for example to test it out.

Comment: @AviMeltser No exception is caught.

Comment: @Lion200 
Nothing has changed.

Comment: @AdriannaTyszkiewicz don't use that serializer to begin with. It's deprecated and even ASP.NET Web API uses Json.NET instead.

Comment: @AdriannaTyszkiewicz as for the rest of the code, if you want to write to a *file*, there's no reason to use a MemoryStream. Just write to the file stream. You should use JSON.NET and simplify the code. A simple` JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myObject)` will return a JSON string that you can write to a file. Or you can use a [JsonSerializer](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingJSON.htm) to write directly to a stream

Comment: Are you sure you want to use [`FileMode.Open`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filemode?view=netframework-4.8)?  *Specifies that the operating system should open an existing file... A FileNotFoundException exception is thrown if the file does not exist.*  Usually when serializing one uses `FileMode.Create` to create or overwrite the old file, or `Append` to create or append to the old file.